# convert a dataframe into yaml file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pyyaml

I am trying to make a yaml file from a dataframe with same entries in one column.

| ID | name |
| --- | --- |
| HN4 | 45_a |
| HN4 | 46_a |
| HN4 | 47_a |

I tried this code, but doesnot work

```
df = pd.read_csv("input.txt",delimiter='\t')
df.set_index('ID', inplace = True)
df.columns = ["subject"]
dfdict = df.to_dict('list')
```

yaml.dump(dfdict)

The output I am looking for is

```
 subject:
         HN4: `
               45_a 
               45_a 
               45_a
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('input.txt', delimiter='\t')
out = yaml.dump({'subject': df.groupby('ID')['name'].apply(list).to_dict()})
print(out)

# Output
subject:
  HN4:
  - 45_a
  - 46_a
  - 47_a
```

Comment: that works. thank you!. Is there a way to remove the "-" from the yaml file?

Comment: If you remove `'-'`, your list will be interpreted as raw text